Como Pasar Valores de Filas a Columnas Segun Index
Apartir del siguiente dataframe ejemplo:
    idx=[1,3,1,2,2,4,5,3,3,1,1]

    C=["A","B","A","C","B","D","C","A","B","A","C"]

    V=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110]

    d={"Categoria":C,"Values":V}

    df=pd.DataFrame(d,index=idx)




Idx
Categoria
Valores




1
A
10


3
B
20


1
A
30


2
C
40


2
B
50


4
D
60


5
C
70


3
A
80


3
B
90


1
A
100


1
C
110



Deseo obtener un dataframe con columnas de los valores de Categorias(A,B,C,D)segun index  con los valores totales; de tal forma que resultado sea:



Idx
A
B
C
D




1
140

110



2

50
40



3
80
110




4



60


5


70





puedes hacerlo asi:
result = df.pivot_table(
    index="Idx", #indices 
    columns="Categoria", #columnas
    values="Valores", # valores como valores
    aggfunc="sum", # y se suman los valores
    fill_value=0 # se rellena con 0 las filas nan
).reset_index()

